# How to pass current user email to Power Automate using site script

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-flow, provisioning, site-design, site-script

I want to trigger Power Automate through site design (inside site script). Found [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview) from MS on how to implement this. There is a way to trigger flow using `triggerFlow` verb and with `When Http Request is Received` action. But I want to pass currently logged in user email address or user id or at least a display name to my flow as parameter. What is the way to pass? Reason behind this is, I need to send email notification through flow who applied that particular site design. Below is sample format

```
{
    "$schema": "schema.json",
    "actions": [
    {
            "verb": "triggerFlow",
            "url": "[paste the workflow trigger URL here]",
            "name": "Apply Template",
            "parameters": {
                "userId":"????????????????????????????",
                "userEmail":"?????????????????????????"
            }
    }
    ],
    "bindata": {},
    "version": 1
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried the steps provided here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-trigger-flow-tutorial But thought this might helpful to you. As it looks similar to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Those parameters are inbuilt parameters only

Comment: inbuilt means, who is running the site designs, that email will be send to flow?

Comment: What I mean is that you can use the following parameters:
      "creatorName": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "creatorEmail": {
        "type": "string"
      }
It only works for Communication sites (-WebTemplate "68"), but I succesfully recovered the creator mail.
Follow these steps as Dikesh mentioned:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-trigger-flow-tutorial
But remember to change the web template. Hope it helps!